# Problema com select UNION ALL mysql

Tags: mysql

Galera montei o seguinte select em MYSQL:

```
                SELECT 
            id_produto, 
            SUM(qtd) as qtd 
        FROM 
         (
             SELECT 
                id, 
                id_produto, 
                qtd 
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos 
            WHERE
                id_pedido = '1'
       UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                id, 
                id_produto, 
                qtd 
            FROM 
                pedidos_barganha
            WHERE
                id_pedido = '1'
                and tipo = 'b'
        ) res
        GROUP BY 
            id_produto
```

Eu rodo ele no PHPMYADMIN e funciona, porém ele esta dando alguns erros no editor, e eu não sei o que pode ser.

Vou postar a fotos aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual editor você está usando?

Comment: @carla phpmyadmin

Comment: já tentou outro editor http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2? veja se ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo atualizar o editor. Essa sintaxe é válida e você mesmo disse que funciona se executar no PHPMyAdmin. Sugiro ainda tentar executar direto pelo client do MySQL. Pode ser que o editor que você está usando não faça o parsing adequado das queries, por isso para o editor está errado, mas para o MySQL não.

Para lidar com banco de dados, recomendo o Squirrel SQL.